# Expected behavior of `find -depth` if execute permission denied for subdirectory?

Tags: permissions, find, directory

I'd like to know if I can rely on the behavior I am seeing when using `find` with `-depth` option and user does not have execute permission for a subdirectory.

Assume the following directory structure:

```
drwxrwxrwt. 10 root    root     12288 Mar 14 04:31 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 24 root    root      4096 Dec  6 03:33 ..
drwx------   4 root    root      4096 Mar 14 04:03 jen
```

Run the following command as non-root user:

```
find -type d
```

The output is:

```
.
./jen
find: `./jen': Permission denied
```

So `find` found the directory *jen* and output that. It then tried to descend into *jen*, but didn't have permission so it printed the error. The first line above is printed to `stdout` and the second line to `stderr`.

Now run the following as non-root user:

```
find -depth -type d
```

And the output is:

```
find: `./jen': Permission denied
.
```

So the pathname is not output to `stdout` unless the user has permission to list the contents of the directory.

This output is perfect for what I want to do. However, I'm not sure if this is just a coincidence or not. **Can I rely on this behavior?**

I'm using GNU findutils 4.4.2. I'm wondering if this behavior is the same across all versions of `find`. And if not, is it at least the same across all versions of GNU find.

It doesn't matter to me (for this use case) whether or not *jen* is printed in the first example. I'm just wondering if I can ***depend*** on it being excluded when `-depth` is used. Normally, it's not a good idea to rely on undocumented behavior. But, to me, this side effect makes sense. So I'm thinking that this might be the *intended* behavior.

The manual says:

> — Option: **-depth**
>
> Process each directory's contents before the directory itself.

This is *exactly* what I want, but it's not clear that the pathname of the directory itself will be excluded from the output if it doesn't descend into it.

Thanks to a hint from Hauke Laging, I discovered that I can list *only* directories and explicitly exclude directories where permission to list their contents is denied:

```
find -type d \( \( -type d \( \! -executable -or \! -readable \) \) -prune -or -print \)
```

This also has the effect of stopping the "Permission denied" errors because `find` never tries to descend into a directory if it doesn't have permission.

Unfortunately, there are two reasons why this will not work for my needs.

- I want the error messages
- I need the `-depth` option

Quoting from the manual

> If the ‘-depth’ option is in effect, the subdirectories will have already been visited in any case. Hence ‘-prune’ has no effect in this case.

So I am back to where I started.

**It's still not clear whether or not "Process each directory's contents before the directory itself." *also means* "Don't process the directory if you can't process it's contents".**

Comment: Which versions of `find` do you want to consider? On Solaris 10, `find . -type d` prints `"."` to stdout and `"find: cannot read dir ./jen: Permission denied"` to stderr. `find . -depth -type d` prints `"find: cannot read dir ./jen: Permission denied"` to stderr and `"."` to stdout. Neither print `"./jen"` to stdout.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The missing `.` was a copy and paste error. I've updated my question with details about versions and what details I'm hoping I can count on.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I find it strange that Solaris 10 does not print `./jen` for `find . -type d`. It's still part of the contents of `.` even though `find` can't descend into it. What does `./*` glob pattern expand to on Solaris 10? Does it include `./jen`?

Comment: I found it unexpected, too, but that's what it does. `echo ./*` outputs `./jen`. I set up the directory structure to be the same as the OP's. `truss` shows that `find` does `fchdir()` to the open `"."` fd, then `getdents64() = 72`, `lstat64("jen",...) = 0`, `openat(..., "jen", ...) => EACCES`, then it outputs the error message, then `getdents64() = 0`, then cleanup and exit. This is on the most recent free Solaris 10/x86 distro from Oracle, Generic_147148-26, in a ufs partition

Answer (score 2):

Probably the better approach is to handle such directories explicitly. I don't know whether these are standard features but at least with Gnu `find` this is possible:

```
find . \( -type d \( \! -executable -or \! -readable \) \) -prune -or -type d
```

of course, it is also possible to print a message if a directory is ignored:

```
find . \( -type d \( \! -executable -or \! -readable \) \) \
  -printf "Permission denied: %p\n" -prune -or -type d -print
```

Comment: This does not give desired output. The directory structure in question was an example. The real structure includes regular files. With the `-or print`, all file types are printed. I only want directories.

Comment: In addition to the need for excluding regular files, I also want to keep the error messages. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @toxalot I guess it's obvious that `-print` (i.e. the part after the `-or`) is just a dummy which needs to be replaced by whatever you want. E.g. you may change that to `-or -type d`.

Comment: The second prints only directories, excludes directories if no permission to list contents, and prints an error message, which gets me most of the way there. Note that the `-print` after the `-or -type d` is important. You can't just replace `-or -print` with `-or type d` as suggested in the comment. However, since `-prune` has no effect when `-depth` is used, I'm back to my original question.

Comment: @toxalot You can adapt the `-printf` part to whatever you want. Of course, you can print one line with the path and another with the error message. `-print` is needed after the `-or` only if a print command occurs in the first part. You do not need `-prune` (descending into those directories is impossible anyway) so you can use `depth` without problems.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the ***main point*** of my question. I want to be *sure* that the pathname, for directories where contents cannot be listed, is not printed. On my system, it *is* printed even though it didn't descend into it - unless `-depth` is used. However, I don't know if that behavior is coincidental or not. *That's* the question. Your solution gives me no benefits whatsoever, doesn't answer my question, and is much uglier than `find -depth -type d`.

Comment: Also, can the error message be printed to `stderr` while printing the pathnames to `stdout`?

Comment: I do understand the question. The simple fact is that I don't know the answer to it and I don't see anyone trying to answer it. The obvious point is: Either you take the risk of this behaviour being unstable or not. If not then it doesn't matter how ugly the alternative is. The obvious advantage of my solution is that it is official and stable. Printing to `stderr` is possible with `-fprintf /dev/stderr ...`.

Comment: *But* yours does not use `-depth` -- which I need. *And* if I change yours to use `-depth`, *how* is it any different from `find -depth -type d`? Your *alternative* combined with `-depth` is the same thing as `find -depth -type d`. So why use the alternative? The only advantage yours adds that is *official and stable* was due to the use of `-prune` which is *always* false when combined with `-depth`.

Comment: @toxalot It seems you have completely misunderstood my proposal. The `-prune` is just a dummy command. The relevant part is the testing for the permissions.

Comment: But why test for permissions if you are going to print an error message anyway? I stand by my opinion that your proposal offers me no advantages. I don't care about the permissions. I care about ***pruning the pathname*** from the output if its a directory and its contents cannot be listed.

Comment: @toxalot I printed the error message because your question says that you want it. I have shown you everything you need. If you are not willing to adapt that: not my problem. If you do not see any use in what I told you: Good luck waiting for someone else. I am not going to continue this discussion.

Comment: -1 because this does not answer the question. +1 because it taught me a few things. Thank you for the time you put into this.